# adding roles in asp.net mvc 4 application using identity provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application "APP1" which has Entity Framework implemented using the DB First approach. I'm using the automatically generated `Account`-`model`, -`views` and -`controller` for Authentication.

So far, everything seems fine. I can add new users and log in.
My question now is: **How can I add roles to my users?** I basically only need 1 role.

***Additional Information***

*I made 2 small modifications:*

- *I extended the AccountModel with an additional EmailAdress property*
- *I changed the ConnectionString Property so my EF SQL Server Instance is being used instead of a LocalDb*

*The following tables were automatically generated at my EF SQL Server DB*

- *dbo.UserProfile*
- *dbo.webpages_Membership*
- *dbo.webpages_OAuthMembership*
- *dbo.webpages_Roles*
- *dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles*

**UPDATE**

I ended up with creating them manually. See my TSQL Code bellow

```
INSERT INTO webpages_Roles (RoleName) VALUES ('canEdit')
INSERT INTO webpages_UsersInRoles (UserId, RoleId) VALUES (2, 1)
```

To make an `ActionResult` available only for authorized persons with a specific role, I decorated them as follow:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // return View();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Identity v1 or v2?

Comment: Since I'm using mvc4 I assume it's v1

Comment: I don't believe there is any problem in using v2 with MVC4

Answer (score 4):

For Identity v1, the code is:

```
var username = "Fred";
var roleName = "Administrator";
Roles.AddUserToRole(username, roleName);
```

If you are using Identity v2 (assuming you have your userManager object):

```
var username = "Fred";
var roleName = "Administrator";
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
```

Comment: how do I implement this? Do I create e.g. a RolesController and some views where the admin can add roles via gui? or is there a simpler way to add the role(s)? (sry I'm new to mvc)

Comment: That's a different question, you need to implement that user interface yourself.